# MongoDB Driver cannot connect to MySQL server

Tags: mongodb, odbc

I am trying to setup ODBC data configuration for MongoDB but I am getting the below error:

```
[MongoDB][ODBC 1.2(a) Driver] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'
```

I dont understand why this is throwing error related to MySQL. Could you please help me in resolving this error?

Btw, I installed MongoDB (for windows) at my local desktop (localhost) and trying to create a DSN for the same.

Comment: This does not do what you think it does. Please [read the press release](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/odbc-driver-for-the-mongodb-connector-for-business-intelligence) and the very first line *"driver for the [MongoDB Connector for Business Intelligence (BI Connector)](https://www.mongodb.com/products/bi-connector)."*. You need to install that product and that is the thing that "Emulates a MySQL server" and actually talks to MongoDB. It's a **read only** service for *limited* query only access. You probably want a language driver instead.

Comment: Hi Neil, Thank you for your response. I installed the Mongodb Connector for BI. But I am still getting the same error:

 `[MongoDB][ODBC 1.0(w) Driver]Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)`

Btw, I am providing TCP/IP Server as "localhost" and port as 27015

Comment: Hi Neil, I didn't start the mongosqld.exe after installing the BI Connector. Post starting mongosqld.exe, I am able to connect through ODBC Data source. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Go into the mongosqld exe folder and which you'll find in Program Files >> MongoDB >> Connector for BI >> 2.14 >> bin >> **mongosqld.exe** run the exe and check the port number under CMD this might be **3307**

You have to Keep the Same port number while giving input in DNS.
Server Name would be localhost only and then test it.